# Dont click draggable element in Android Chrome

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have draggable element with button. But button don't work on Android Chrome.

```
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Draggable Div</p>
  <div id="clickAction">Click Me! (I should change colour)</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
  $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
  $( "#draggable" ).click(function() {
    console.log('clicked!')
  });

  $( "#clickAction" ).click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('blue')){
       $(this).removeClass('blue');
    }else{
       $(this).addClass('blue');
    }
  });
</script>
```

https://codepen.io/macmadill/full/gbXmZG

The problem is that, drag event go first, and click event don't work

Please, help me. Sorry for my English.

Comment: buttom or button?

Comment: Please post your code here.

Comment: peeebeee, why you need code? Any draggable element with click event

Comment: Shailesh Rathod, sorry)

Comment: The click event on touch devices doesn't fire with `.click(function(){` on many devices. You should use `.on('click', function () {` instead of that.

Answer (score 1):

The code appears to work:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#draggable").draggable();
  $("#draggable").click(function() {
    console.log('clicked!')
  });

  $("#clickAction").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('blue')) {
      $(this).removeClass('blue');
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('blue');
    }
  });
})
```

```css
.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Draggable Div</p>
  <div id="clickAction">Click Me! (I should change colour)</div>
</div>
```

To test on Chrome on Android, I created test fiddle.

- Code: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/pbcrn978/
- Test: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/pbcrn978/show/

My Test Environment:

> Chrome 71.0.3578.99
>
> Android 8.0.0

Click event works, yet Drag does not. You may want to consider adding TouchPunch.

- Code: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/pbcrn978/5/
- Test: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/pbcrn978/5/show/

I am now able to replicate the issue you reported.

I also found the following bug report: https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch/issues/309

I did test with the suggested fix, yet it made no change. This issue was related to event bubbling. So I adjusted the draggable:

```
$("#draggable").draggable({
  handle: "p"
});
```

This worked and the final code test is here.

- Code: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/pbcrn978/16/
- Test: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/pbcrn978/16/show/

Adding the handle meant that the click event for drag was only confined to `<p>` element and thus would not bubble up to the parent. I suspect that the event was capturing the click for drag versus the click event you wanted.

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $("#draggable").draggable({
    handle: "p"
  });

  $("#clickAction").click(function(e) {
    console.log(e.type + " detected");
    if ($(this).hasClass('blue')) {
      $(this).removeClass('blue');
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('blue');
    }
  });
});
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `click` event to `mousedown` event like this:

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable();
$( "#draggable" ).mousedown(function() {
  console.log('clicked!')
});

$( "#clickAction" ).mousedown(function() {
  if($(this).hasClass('blue')){
      $(this).removeClass('blue');
  }else{
    $(this).addClass('blue');
  }
});
```

check this out in [codepen](https://codepen.io/Ismatjon/full/KJKmwr)